# Can I initialize a BCL immutable collection using braces?

Tags: c#, collections, initialization, immutability, base-class-library

In the old days, we could conveniently initialize mutable collections using braces, as in the following example:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"hello", 0m}, {"world", 1m}};
```

Is there a similar syntax that can be used with BCL immutable collections? I understand it is still a pre-release but maybe there is a recommended syntax, or at least this question will serve as feedback to implement these convenient initializers.

In the mean time, the shortest I have found is the following:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal> {{"hello", 0m}, {"world", 1m}}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a similar syntax that can be used with BCL immutable collections?

Not as far as I'm aware - unfortunately both object and collection initializers *rely* on mutability. In that respect it's a shame that the language isn't designed such that if there's an `Add` method with a return value, that can be used as an intermediate value. (That wouldn't help with setting properties in object initializers, mind you, and I prefer the name `Plus` to `Add` to make the semantics clearer.)

I think the approach you're already using is the most appropriate one for a shortcut.

For `ImmutableList` it's slightly simpler:

```
var list = ImmutableList.Create(1, 2, 3);
```

which is *fairly* simple (and allows for type inference) but I don't know of anything similar for `ImmutableDictionary`. There's an overload of `Create` which takes an `IEnumerable<TKey, TValue>`, but constructing any implementation is likely to be as fiddly as just constructing the mutable dictionary as you're already doing.